# how to remove an element in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

I have to remove div element from the grid footer. how to remove using angular js.I have code like myGrid.html

```
 <div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span12">
     <div style="height: 450px; width: 100%;" ng-grid="myGrid"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

and my myGrid.js code looks like this-

```
     $scope.myGrid= {
            data : 'myData',
            showFooter : true,
            enablePaging : true,
            pagingOptions : $scope.pager.pagingOptions,
            enablePinning : true,
            columnDefs : [{
                        field : 'myField_1',
                        displayName : 'MyField_1',
                        width : '300',
                        pinnable : false
                    }, {
                        field : 'myField_2',
                        displayName : 'MyField_2',
                        width : '200',
                        pinnable : false
                    }, {
                        field : 'myField_3',
                        displayName : 'MyField_3',
                        width : '300',
                        pinnable : false
                    }]
        };
```

angular grid comes with footer if showFooter is true in grid options,
here i want to show the footer but i have to remove some div element from footer.could you please help me out, how to remove this specific div elements from grid footer.
the div element is with the class

```
     <div class="ngRowCountPicker"></div>
```

I think this information would be enough to answer and make question specific.
i shall be thankful......

Comment: Is this footer part of the template for the `ng-grid` directive? When you say you want to remove the div do you mean based on a condition?

Answer (score 0):

he [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki/Templating) shows how you can override the html template for ng-grid's **header** template. Unfortunately [ng-grid](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid) doesn't provide the same functionality for overriding the footer.

The easiest thing would be to just add some custom css to your project's stylesheet:

```
div.ngRowCountPicker {
    display: none;
}
```

Another option would be to fork [ng-grid](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid) and customize the template to your liking.

You also could create a `directive` that you use to watch for an element's display state and then hide it whenever it is displayed. Something like this (but this is overkill - just use custom css):

```js
app.directive('removeElement', function () {
   // directive to watch for and hide a given element
   return {
       link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

           var offendingElement,
               offendingElementSelector = attrs.removeElement;

           scope.$watch(
               function () {
                   offendingElement = $(offendingElementSelector);
                   return offendingElement.css('display');
               }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                   if ( newValue !== 'none' ) {
                       // assuming you're using JQuery
                       offendingElement.hide();
                   }
               });
        }
    };
});
```

In your html you would use it like this:

```
<div class="span12">
  <div style="height: 450px; width: 100%;" ng-grid="myGrid"></div>
  <div remove-element="div.ngRowCountPicker"></div>
</div>
```

The downside of something like this is your adding an extra query selection to every `$digest` cycle just to turn an element off.

You can see this at work in [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ojiyav/1).